# Vertical title heading for table columns (in Firefox and Chrome)

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I am trying to make my table column titles veritcal as portrayed and described here:
[Vertical Column Headers](http://geekswithblogs.net/thanigai/archive/2009/05/21/vertical-column-headers.aspx)

the code used:

```
    <style type="text/css">

.VertiColumn th {

writing-mode: tb-rl;

filter: fliph() flipV();

}

</style>
```

However it only works for IE not any other browser, can anyone help?

Comment: Just posted an answer :) Did it help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you could use some other CSS code for that. Working fiddle (tested in FF 3.6 and Chrome 13.0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mdHB3/1/

Taken from this site: http://css3please.com/

Comment: This does not work for larger headers, this perhaps shows a direction http://jsfiddle.net/g73j7/